# How to using sed, remove Chinese characters in comments?

Tags: regex, sed, utf-8

i need to remove the comments, the sed command i have test:

```
xargs -i sed -i -e '/^\s*#[^!]/D' -e '/^\s*#$/D'
```

this command used keep #!XXX and remove #XXX, but when i check the result after exe the sed , I find the Chinese characters can not matching，the encode type: ansi(use BeyondCompare check)

if I open the file with vim(SUSE11.3) it looks like unreadable codes, following are opened with beyondcompare and vim, the last is test result,please help

```
#修改json
modules_names_arr = ModulesConfigUtils.read_modules_name
modules_names_arr.each do |module_name|
    module_config_hash = ModulesConfigUtils.read_module_config(module_name)
    if module_config_hash.nil?
        next
        end
#修改每个模块的参数

#DT??json
modules_names_arr = ModulesConfigUtils.read_modules_name
modules_names_arr.each do |module_name|
    module_config_hash = ModulesConfigUtils.read_module_config(module_name)
    if module_config_hash.nil?
        next
        end 
#DT???????￡?éμ?2

sed -e '/^\s*#[^!]/D' -e '/^\s*#$/D' bak_ciphertext.rb | grep "^\s*#"                   
    #О?īson
        #О?????????±???八·??#
```

Comment: Your command works for me. Have you tried setting the locale to a UTF-8 locale, e.g. `LC_ALL="en_AU.UTF-8"`? What does `locale` output? Do you get the same error when creating a UTF-8 file in vim? What's the encoding of your files?

Comment: thanks,this is my display: # locale 
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Works for me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your locale. Open the file in vim, run `:set fenc` to see the encoding of your file. If it's not UTF-8, use `:set fenc=utf-8` to change the encoding of your file and use `:w` to write your changes. Then run the sed command again.